# When solving trigonometric irrational equations does the condition of existence of the radicand under an even root matter?

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Hi everyone I would like to ask a thing about the following equation:

$$\cos(x) + \sqrt[4]{1 - \frac{4}{3}\cos(2x) - \sin^4(x)} = 0$$

It is trigonometric and irrational, the root's index is 4 (even root).

Now, given that:

$$a = b \implies a^4 = b^4 $$

But:

$a^4 = b^4\,\,$ does not necessarily mean that $a = b$, how should I handle it with the equation above? Should I care about the conditions of existence of the 4th root?

I mean:

$1 - \frac{4}{3}\cos(2x) - \sin^4(x) \ge 0$ ?

Or, can I just do the following:

$$\sqrt[4]{1 - \frac{4}{3}\cos(2x) - \sin^4(x)} = -\,cos(x)$$

And raise both members to the power of 4 so that:

$$1 - \frac{4}{3}\cos(2x) - \sin^4(x) = \cos^4(x)$$

And solve the equation remembering that $\cos(x)$ must be $\le 0$ ???

Is this enough? Will solving the system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
1 - \frac{4}{3}\cos(2x) - \sin^4(x) = \cos^4(x)\\
\cos(x) \le 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

give me all the solutions for the equation but only the true solutions for which $1 - \frac{4}{3}\cos(2x) - \sin^4(x)$ is greater than or equal to 0?

Or should I compute all the cases under the root when the radicand can be negative?

Just need some elucidation. Thanks for the attention!

Comment: What do you mean by an equation being "irrational"?

Comment: well just be sure to check for extraneous solutions

Comment: @GFauxPas irrational in the sense that there's a root with a variables in it.

Comment: @ZachL ok, but how should I do that once I have solved it?

Comment: @user3019105 remembering that $\cos x$ should be negative is enough to avoid extraneous solutions in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your start is correct.

All the solutions of the equation:

$$1 - \frac{4}{3}\cos(2x) - \sin^4(x) = \cos^4(x)$$

necessarily have $1 - \frac{4}{3}\cos(2x) - \sin^4(x)\geq 0$. There is no reason to add that condition.

Adding the condition that you need $\cos(x)\leq 0$ gives you what you want.

The next step is to write everything as an equation of $\cos^2(x)$ - both $\cos(2x)$ and $\sin^4(x)$ can be written in terms of $\cos^2(x)$.

If $X=\cos^2(x)$, you get the equation:

$$1-\frac{4}{3}(2X-1) -(1-X)^2 = X^2$$

Solve for $X$, choose only the non-negative roots, then find solve $\cos(x)=-\sqrt{X}$ for those $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I still didn't understand one thing. You say that all the solutions of the equation with both terms raised to the power of 4 have the left term necessarily greater than equal to 0. But is it so because of the right term ($cos^4(x)$), is that correct? But if there wasn't a $cos^4(x)$ on the right, would this statement still be true or not?